# Formatting Lightning Lead Page Layouts

Tags: lightning, page-layout, fields

Is there anyway to format the field layout when creating a new lead? My current new lead layout looks misformatted.

[image]

While the page layout looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's still showing you the fields as on your page layout. Except for that the Name field as rendered is the compound field and thus shows every other attributes viz., Salutation, First Name, and Last Name.

Comment: Could this be a Salesforce render issue then? I would have assumed that phone would display properly beside name, and that a compounded field in a 2 column layout wouldn't affect both columns

Comment: No. Phone is still being displayed where it is supposed to be shown, besides Company. It's the Email field which should come beside Name, which is how it is being rendered. It's just the additional attributes in Name which is causing the other part of the column rendered with white space after Email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display on the new Lead screen matches exactly as how its configured in the Page Layout. It's just how its displayed in Lightning vs. Classic.

Because the `Name` field constitutes of all other attributes when rendered on UI additionally renders the `Salutation`, `First Name`, and `Last Name` and giving an impression that it's not rendered appropriately. You still have the order of fields maintained as you have configured in your page layout, i.e., `Email` is just besides `Name` and then followed by `Company` and `Phone`.

In Classic, the empty real estate is filled in with the other fields in the other column, whereas in Lightning it renders the other column with empty spaces and that the order of the fields as configured in page layout is maintained.